# Unable to get the proper result

Tags: android

Here is my function..

```
public Cursor fetchAllAlarmGreaterByDate(long appDate, int appTime) {

    return mDb.query(ALARM_TABLE, null, ALARM_DATE + ">" + appDate
            + " and " + ALARM_TIME + ">" + appTime, null, null, null,
            ALARM_DATE + " ASC" + " and " + ALARM_TIME + " ASC");

}
```

I am unable to get result in asc on both column ALARM_DATE AND ALARM_TIME (it gives syntax error).

If I use only ALARM_DATE + " ASC" then it doesn't give any error but the problem is that it also doesn't give any result.

How to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public Cursor fetchAllAlarmGreaterByDate(long appDate, int appTime) {return mDb.query(ALARM_TABLE, null, ALARM_DATE + ">" + appDate  + " and " + ALARM_TIME + ">" + appTime, null, null, null,             ALARM_DATE + " ASC" + " , " + ALARM_TIME + " ASC");  }
```

just replace the"AND" in your query with "," for ASC

Answer (score 0):

```
return mDb.query(ALARM_TABLE, null, ALARM_DATE + " > " + appDate
            + " and " + ALARM_TIME + " > " + appTime, null, null, null,
            ALARM_DATE + ", " + ALARM_TIME + " ASC");

}
```

Try the above. This should solve the syntax error. What are the types of the ALARM_DATE and ALARM_TIME columns in your table?